# I am trying to deploy a python app using AWS EB CLI (elastic beanstalk)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does anybody know why I am not being prompted to supply credentials.

[the error after entering  $ eb init](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1Q9.png)

Comment: `eb init` will expect you to have some credentials saved locally, do you know if those are in place on your machine? They are usually located in your home directory (osx) in a hidden folder (folder naming convention starting with a period). You might expect two files `config` and `credentials` (each with name only, no filetype extension). A common osx location would be: `~/.aws/config` This file will include some preferred defaults as well as `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` which you would have generated previously via AWS `IAM`

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below:

1. Navigate to [Your Security Credentials](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credentials)
2. Under **Access keys (access key ID and secret access key)** create a new set of Access and Secret Keys
3. Download the Secret Key
4. Type `aws configure` in your terminal
5. Enter the **Access Key**, **Secret Key** and **Region** when prompted. (region is us-east-1 if you are using N. Virginia, for more information check [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html))
6. Now try `eb init`

> Note: In future you should create a new user with permissions to do eb
>   deployments and use the access key and secret key pair of that user.
>   For testing purposes you can use your root user credentials. But make
>   sure to delete the credentials from the [Credentials page](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#/security_credentials) when you
>   are done.

Comment: This was exactly correct so thank you for this extremely useful tip!

Comment: Could you mark the answer as correct since this worked for you?